# How to check whether a previous drop-down parameter had only one value chosen?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have two parameters, `@AccountID` and `@SourceType`, and they are both drop-downs.

Here is the declaration of the `@SourceType` parameter in the stored procedure:

```
@SourceType BIT = NULL,
/*
 * Works if @AccountID is not null
 * (should only be used if @AccountID has a single value)
 *
 * 0 - Owned by @AccountID
 * 1 - External (not owned by @AccountID)
 */
```

It should only be selectable, if AccountID has a single value (and it's a multi-select with about 50 options).

Comment: Just to clarify - is this sproc called when you change the value of your AccountID parameter? In other words, the proc is the data source of the SourceType parameter?

Comment: @GShenanigan,  Yes, exactly  - the SPROC basically takes the `@AccountID` parameter as a varchar and comma-separates it

Comment: I'm not sure if you can disable the SourceType parameter on the result of AccountID, but your proc logic could handle it and return a null value if the AccountID is a single value.  Would that do you?

Comment: @Adel Does SourceType perameter have its own dataset for the dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you create a dataset that looks at the `@AccountId` parameter and returns options based on the number of values selected.

Using the count attribute of a parameter will enable you to check if more than one value was selected. E.g. `Parameters!Parameter.Count`.

Then based on the number of returned counts you can set the `@SourceType` parameter options.